# Get the global locale that is currently set in C++?

Tags: c++, locale

In C++, I can *set* the current locale like this:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale(name))
```

But how can I *get* the current global locale?

In my code, I need to get the current locale, save it to a tmp var, set the global locale to something else, output something, then set it back to the previous locale.

Comment: Haven't used it, but is this what you're after? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/getloc edit: never mind, I found the return value is the current locale. See Corbin's answer.

Comment: Do you want the global locale (defaulting to `"C"`), or the environment's locale?

Comment: I want the value of whatever someone set before using `std::locale::global`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you call the default constructor of `std::locale`, you get it.

```
std::locale the_global_locale; // <-- automatically correct to std::locale::global
                               //     or a copy of std::locale::classic
```

More info here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale

Answer (score 5):

Its return value is the old locale, so just use that.

```
locale l = locale::global(locale(name));
//do some stuff here
locale::global(l);
```

Edit: Potentially useful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/global

Answer (score 2):

As ipc says, the default constructor for std::locale gives you a copy of the current global locale, but why do you need to cache and then reset the global locale?

C++ routines that use a locale can typically use a C++ locale object you specify, so you don't have to mess with the global locale at all. Using locale objects should be preferred to using the C++ global locale.